# Is it necessary to write a parser for rendering Facebook's draft.js data on native Android app?

Tags: javascript, android, draftjs

I've used [draft.js](https://draftjs.org/) for my website's rich text editor. If I tend to build a native android app, should I need to write a custom parser to extract text styles in draft.js data(maybe json or markdown) for rendering?

Comment: let will be a great project!